# Russian String Formatting in Flowable

Tags: python, reportlab

There have been many posts about how to use `reportlab` to create foreign text using `drawString` or `drawCentredString`, but I am struggling to wrap the text in a `Paragraph` or `Frame`.

The code below works to print the Russian text when called explicitly, but when using paragraph and frame it fails:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter
from reportlab.lib.units import inch
from reportlab.platypus import Paragraph, Frame
from reportlab.lib.styles import getSampleStyleSheet

#Set the Arial font
from reportlab.pdfbase import pdfmetrics 
from reportlab.pdfbase.ttfonts import TTFont 
pdfmetrics.registerFont(TTFont('Arial', 'Arial.ttf'))

#Set Dimensions of the sheet
width, height = letter
margin = 0.5*inch
mwidth = width - 2*margin
mheight = height - 2*margin

#Set the styles to Centered and Arial
styleSheet = getSampleStyleSheet()
style = styleSheet['Normal']
style.alignment = 1
style.font = "Arial"
style.fontSize = 14


def Fill_Canvas(c):
    #Create Border
    c.translate(margin,margin)
    c.setLineWidth(4)
    c.rect(0,0, mwidth, mheight)

    #Create Line
    c.translate(0,mheight-inch)
    c.line(0.5*inch ,0,mwidth - 0.5*inch,0)


    #Create Russia Text
    c.setFont("Arial",36)
    c.translate(0,-inch)
    c.drawCentredString(mwidth/2,0,u"ТЕХНИЧЕСКИЙ ПАСПОРТ".encode('utf-8'))
    c.translate(0,-.75*inch)
    c.drawCentredString(mwidth/2,0,u"HA".encode('utf-8'))

    #Create description
    c.translate(0, -.75*inch)
    f = Frame(0,0, mwidth, 0.5*inch,showBoundary=1)
    story = []
    story.append(Paragraph(u"Sample russian text: ТЕХНИЧЕСКИЙ ПАСПОРТ".encode('utf-8'),style))
    f.addFromList(story,c)

#Create PDF
c = canvas.Canvas("Hello.pdf",pagesize = letter)
Fill_Canvas(c)
c.showPage()
c.save()
```

Any hints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was not the `Paragraph` or the `Frame`, but rather that I needed to set `style.fontName = 'Arial'` instead of 'style.font`.

Comment: It won't let me for a couple of days...But I will!